Chain Link ORACLE NODE Error when calling the transfer function of a smart contract with an amount ranging from 10 to 18
I am setting up an Oracle node that uses a webhook job to call a transfer function of a smart contract. The amount entered by the user will be multiplied by 10 to the power of 18 and then sent to the webhook job. However, when I input an amount from 10 to 18, the Oracle node automatically converts it into a very large number, for example:     115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039449137263839420088320.
This causes the transaction to fail.
 Job definition:
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = ""
externalJobID = "0641125c-1536-4858-a4a5-f27ef0eb5dd5"
forwardingAllowed = false
observationSource = """
    encode_data [
        type="ethabiencode"
        abi="makePayment(string _requestId, address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount, uint8 _truckNumber)"
        data="{\"_requestId\": \"7adaf7d3-3ec0-48b3-95d8-a9feb173febc\", \"_from\": \"0x278Aa2e37496cD0A6370E334406C0D0D9c51e7Bc\", \"_to\": \"0x7C1748faFeF376B913A27AF7b1b0f4EFDb27762d\", \"_amount\": 10000000000000000000, \"_truckNumber\": 41}"
    ]
    call_contract [
        type="ethtx"
        data="$(encode_data)"
        evmChainID="11155111"
        to="0x41900d520189b6eC2ee09031Ac01A4336906274a"
    ]

    encode_data -> call_contract

Here is the outputs from My Chainlink GUI for this job run:
Raw hex:
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
Data:
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
Transaction: https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x74c71c9c91ec3f42df705337ebce6d2cd043418ef0c8ccd4608761735ef3026d
Response Oracle node: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z_GKAJunnpnod6b5dHHJv-c-bHQ6FRsB/view?usp=sharing
Can someone explain what happens when the input amount is between 10 and 18 or suggest a way to fix this issue? Thank you very much!

Hi Trung, Chainlink published a new product called Chainlink Functions. Functions can help you to fetch data from any API to smart contract. Your way, any API with the Chainlink node is not currently recommended. Is is possible for you to use Chainlink Functions?(https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/getting-started)
